# Slideshow salta de la imagen 1 a la 4

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hola estoy practicando haciendo un slideshow y me salta de la imagen 1 a la 4.

```js
var imgs = document.getElementById("idimg").getElementsByTagName("img");
 var i = 0;

 function slideshow () {
  for(var n = i; n <= imgs.length; n++){
   imgs[i].style.zIndex = "5";
  }
 }

 setInterval(slideshow, 500);
```

```css
.uno {
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 1;
  }
  .dos {
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 2;
  }
  .tres {
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 3;
  }
  .cuatro {
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 4;
  }
```

```html
<div id="idimg">
 <img class="uno" src="image-1.gif">
 <img class="dos" src="image-2.gif">
 <img class="tres" src="image-3.gif">
 <img class="cuatro" src="image-4.gif">
</div>
```

Comment: En tu for imgs[i] no deberias poner imgs[n]?

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, Solo necesitas un contenedor donde muestres las imagenes, te sugiero revisar el for. Recuerda revisar [ask] y No olvides realizar el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio, saludos!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para que obtengas todos los elementos `<img` te sugiero usar la variable `i`, inicializarla e incrementarla hasta el valor de la cantidad de elementos `imgs.length` :

```
function slideshow () {
       for(var i = 0; i <= imgs.length; i++){
           img.src =  imgs[i].src;
        }
    }
```

Si deseas realizar un slide te sugiero lo realices de esta forma, donde solo necesitas un elemento `<img` donde se mostrarían las imágenes definidas en el arreglo:

```
    window.onload = function() {
    var image=document.getElementById("aaa");
    var img_array=["image-1.gif","image-2.gif","image-3.gif","image-4.gif"];
    var index=0;
    var interval = 500;
    function slide() {
        document.getElementById("myimage").src = img_array[index++%img_array.length];
    }

    setInterval(slide, interval);
}
```

---

Ejemplo:

```js
    window.onload = function() {
    var image=document.getElementById("aaa");
    var img_array=["https://media.wired.com/photos/5926db217034dc5f91becd6b/master/w_1904,c_limit/so-logo-s.jpg","https://responsivedesign.is/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/be-inspired.svg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5712c8b91d07c0fc4a29034d/t/59b010946e9329024be40bd4/1504655639343/6010d66c21d9b0090027d8e89641a467-idea-light-bulb-school-by-vexels.png","https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/84/Example.svg", "https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JLYC.png"];
    var index=0;
    var interval = 500;
    function slide() {
  document.getElementById("myimage").src = img_array[index++%img_array.length];
    }

    setInterval(slide, interval);
}
```

```html
<div id="imagenes">
   <img id="myimage" width="100px" height="100px">
</div>
```

Comment: Este codigo es para imagenes online como se adapta para local. Hay una variable image que es undefined.